# GCC warning when compiling Orange

Tags: gcc, c++

When I try to install Orange (http://orange.biolab.si/download/) on ubuntu, I get these messages:

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC \
    -I/usr/include/python2.7 \
    -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include \
    -Isource/include -Isource/orange/liblinear \
    -Isource/orange/ppp -Isource/orange/px \
    -I/usr/include/python2.7 \
    -c source/orange/tdidt_clustering.cpp \
    -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/source/orange/tdidt_clustering.o \
    -fPIC -w -DLINUX -DORANGE_EXPORTS
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for Ada/C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
```

What does it mean? And what should I do?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699854/why-is-gccs-option-wstrict-prototypes-not-valid-for-c

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: I believe it means you don't need to specify it (`‘-Wstrict-prototypes’), because it is already the default. The question Celada linked to covers this pretty throughly. In any case, this is a programming question, so OT here. Note that moving to SO is not appropriate, since it has already been answered there - I think it is a dupe of the link.

Comment: It's a warning not an error. If your building fails is for another reason.

Comment: Reviewers, please don't vote for closing any more so that this doesn't get migrated to SO. I have flagged this for the mods to delete it.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Do you mean to say that any question where there is a compiler error/warning is automatically not OT on U&L?

Comment: I closed and reopened this since it was going to be migrated to [so] where it is a duplicate. I don't see why this is off topic here but if that's what you all feel, close it again, just don't migrate.

Comment: @Anthon I would say that. It seems quite strange to me to make a difference (in the sense of: Where does the question belong?) between compiler errors due to code errors and compiler errors due to command line errors (which are compiler-specific).

Comment: MrJonas, did the installation work? Is it correctly installed? If so, you have no problems here and you can ignore the warnings.

Comment: @HaukeLaging we should take this to meta but I'm with Anthon. The basic question here is about installing software on *nix which is clearly on topic. I think the OP was just looking for the answer that Anthon gave, not for an SO-style explanation of what that error message really means.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I disagree and so it seems do others.

Comment: @Anthon see discussion with terdon on chat. I'm not sure I'm convinced, but I don't care to argue the matter. Note that OT is ambiguous. I can mean either On Topic of Off Topic, but my experience has been that it is mostly used to mean Off Topic.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything as these are warnings not errors.

What you could do is notify the maintainers of the package and let them know that warnings are confusing to the non-initiated and if they can get rid of them. If you do make sure to provide them with your setup information, as they might not see the warning in theirs.